# Spacy: Should I train the model on single sentence or I can pass two sentence combined?

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction

I have multiple sentences like the one below in my database:

> KP Snacks Ltd recalls certain date codes of 4 variants of McCoy’s
>   multi bag crisps. KP Snacks Ltd has undertaken a precautionary recall
>   of the products listed below as a very small number of these bags of
>   crisps may contain small pieces of plastic.

Should I first split the sentences or I can just the whole data (2 sentences) to the model?

```
TRAIN_DATA_1 = [
    ("KP Snacks Ltd recalls certain date codes of 4 variants of McCoy’s multi bag crisps. KP Snacks Ltd has undertaken a precautionary recall of the products listed below as a very small number of these bags of crisps may contain small pieces of plastic.", {"entities": []}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": []}),
]

TRAIN_DATA_2 = [
    ("KP Snacks Ltd recalls certain date codes of 4 variants of McCoy’s multi bag crisps.", {"entities": []}),
("KP Snacks Ltd has undertaken a precautionary recall of the products listed below as a very small number of these bags of crisps may contain small pieces of plastic.", {"entities": []}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": []}),
]
```

In short, TRAIN_DATA_1 vs TRAIN_DATA_2 which is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I first split the sentences or I can just the whole data (2 sentences) to the model?

It depends. Everything is related to your purposes.

**It looks like you're training a NER**. In this case, multiple shorter phrases are better, since NER depends on surrounding words for entity prediction - therefore, if you provide too large texts, parts of them will either be ignored by the parser (depends on the tool) or will impact your results (negativelly).

> In short, TRAIN_DATA_1 vs TRAIN_DATA_2 which is correct and why?

There's no "correct" answer. As mentioned, it depends on the tool and purpose. **I'd recommend splitting, since you'll be able to produce more data samples for better training.**

The exception goes for the case of coreference resolution, since parts of the second split phrase may refer to the first one. But I assume that this is a rare case.

This may also be the case with sentiment analysis and other end tasks where you have several periods pertaining to a single statement that was already classified and cannot be broken without information/sense lost.